# Iterate through views module results

Tags: views, theming

I am using the views module to show a block of 4 projects on my homepage.
This view uses `node--project.tpl.php` to show a project in this view.

What i now want to do is assign a class in `node--project.tpl.php` to my node which depends on an iterator. This iterator should match the **row iterator** around it. (The row iterator always assigns a class to the row around the node. ex. views-row-1, views-row-2, views-row-3 .. and so on.)

What i want to is: node 1 should get the class 'grid-1-4', node 2 and node 3 should get the class 'grid-1-8'. node 4 should get the class 'grid-1-2'. By these nodes i mean the nodes from my views block result.

Is there a way to pass by this iterator (i think it comes from **sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-unformatted.tpl.php**) to my rendered nodes? Or is there another way to iterate through my view which could solve my problem?